# How to put an element (a grid) under an image?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have built a grid, and centered it in the middle of the page with `top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%);`

The code above centered the grid exactly as i needed it to, in the middle of the page, but it also seems to have put the grid over the image. I need to put the grid under the image, centered in the middle of the screen.

```css
.card {
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 2px;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 188px;
    width: 255px;
    margin: 1rem;
    position: relative;
}

.card-1 {
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
    transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(.25,.8,.25,1);
}

.card-1:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(0,0,0,0.25), 0 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);
}

.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
    gap: 0px 0px;
    grid-template-areas:
            ". . ."
            ". . .";
    max-width: 60%;
    position: fixed; 
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Dogodki</title>
</head>
<body>

        <div id="test1">
            <img src="https://htmlcolorcodes.com/assets/images/html-color-codes-color-palette-generators.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="grid-container">
            <div class="card card-1"></div>
            <div class="card card-1"></div>
            <div class="card card-1"></div>
            <div class="card card-1"></div>
            <div class="card card-1"></div>
            <div class="card card-1"></div>
        </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What would be the point? You won't be able to see anything through the image. Anyway, just add `z-index:-1` to your grid container.

Comment: I have troubles to understand your question. What exactly is the purpose and the intended outcome? What is the purpose of: `grid-template-areas: ". . ."  ". . .";`? declaring a grid and then setting the area with empty content seems pointless to me. Same as `gap: 0px 0px;` is superfluous. It could be shorten to `gap: 0;` which would be the default property and value in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that what you are trying to do ?

```css
.card {
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 2px;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 188px;
    width: 255px;
    margin: 1rem;
    position: relative;
}

.card-1 {
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
    transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(.25,.8,.25,1);
}

.card-1:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(0,0,0,0.25), 0 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);
}

.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
    gap: 0px 0px;
    grid-template-areas:
            ". . ."
            ". . .";
    max-width: 60%;
    position: relative; 
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Dogodki</title>
</head>
<body>

        <div id="test1">
            <img src="https://htmlcolorcodes.com/assets/images/html-color-codes-color-palette-generators.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="grid-container">
            <div class="card card-1"></div>
            <div class="card card-1"></div>
            <div class="card card-1"></div>
            <div class="card card-1"></div>
            <div class="card card-1"></div>
            <div class="card card-1"></div>
        </div>


</body>
</html>
```